# Is this set recursively enumerable, recursive and semantically closed?

Tags: computability, formal-languages

my questions are:

[set with n equals or under 100 and infinite domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njDLU.png)

- the set A is recursively enumerable?
- the set A is recursive?
- the set A is semantically closed?
- the complementary set ( $ \overline{A} $ ) is recursively enumerable ?

**My try:** since n is bounded I should be able to compute this function. So the function belong to the set $R$ (recursive) and $RE$ (Recursively enumerable).
But I have some dubs about the infinite domain of function  $  {\displaystyle \varphi } $ because maybe this could make my set non-computable.

I'm sorry for my bad grammar as I'm not a native English speaker but I would appreciate any advice for help me to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does "semantically closed" mean in this context?

Comment: **Hint** for the other questions: _Every_ finite set is recursive.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have some dubs but it should mean that all element of the description of the set don't need any extra definition. For example function  $  {\displaystyle \varphi } $ could be undefined because (at least for me) it is a generic function and I don't know how to calculate it. But I'm not sure about..

Comment: What does it mean for a number to "need any extra definition"? Can you give an example of a number that "needs any extra defintion" and a number that doesn't?

Comment: I was talking about symbol  $  {\displaystyle \varphi } $  that is not a number but a function that take a parameter (n) and give some output. The definition above don't give a definition about what function  $  {\displaystyle \varphi } $  is or does.
This is why I don't understand if the set is finite.

Comment: The set consists of natural numbers that are less than or equal to 100. There are only 101 such numbers that _could_ be in your set -- how can the set _not_ be finite?

Comment: I just don't have fully understood what $ dom \   {\displaystyle \varphi }  \ (n)  \ infinite $ mean

Comment: Usually $\varphi_n$ in this context means the function computed by the $n$th Turing machine according to some enumeration. It has infinite domain if the $n$th Turing machine terminates for infinitely many different inputs.

Comment: Based on your hints I think that these are **some** correct answers:  
- A is recursive --> since it is finite  
- A is recursively enumerable since it is ricorsive  
I have some dubs about $ \overline{A} $  to be recursively enumerable since I can't find a theorem that suit my needs

Comment: Can you prove that the complement of a recursive set is recursive?

Comment: Is possible to prove that: For all sets A, if A ∈ R then Ā ∈ R. But not the opposite, I think.

Comment: Surely, by the argument you're describing, if $\bar A$ is recursive, then $\bar{\bar A}$ is recursive too?

Comment: I don't know for sure.

Comment: You wrote "for all sets" yourself. Does $\bar A$ not count as one of "all sets"?

Comment: Yes, if $ \overline{ \overline{A} } = A $ then $ \overline{A} $ is ecursively enumerable. If I understand correctly.